# How to repeatedly rotate a point in GeoGebra

Tags: math, graph, chemistry, orbital-mechanics, geogebra

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArqXT.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GFxN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUEKA.png)

Hello, I am a student studying GeoGebra in Korea.
I'm having trouble writing formulas, so I'm leaving a question.

1. the brown graph represents the probability of an electron being present (relative value: the sum of the areas is not equal to 1), but when I integrate from 0 to infinity, I don't get a value. Is the expression too complicated for GeoGebra to solve?
2. I want to plot the probability that an electron exists as a dot plot. My idea is as follows.

1. Where there is a high probability of an electron being found, there should be a lot of electrons.
2. Therefore, I have divided the x-axis of the graph into units of 0.1. (In the picture, this is designated as variable a).
3. This is a formula I can't write, help!
   At the corresponding x(=a) value, rotate 360 degrees/probability (probability is a decimal number, so I'm going to multiply it by 100 to make it a natural number).  So if the probability*100 is, say, 36, I'd do 36 rotations of 10 degrees to get 36 dots, and if the probability is 60, I'd do 6 rotations of 10 degrees for a total of 60 dots.
   How could we write this expression? Help.

Comment: Remember to read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) (yep, it's a bit long, just read the whole thing once, and then you'll never have to read it again =) and [edit] you post accordingly.

Comment: Can you add a formula text code instead of image? This is tutorial, how to add text(or source) in [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). It will help to easy reproduce your graph and help your problem.